# Can I use SSIS package with SQL Server Workgroup Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Is it possible for me to use SSIS package with SQL Server Workgroup Edition.
Please note that I don’t have deep knowledge of SSIS tools, so not sure which license I need to run the SSIS package my company is looking to buy.
The selling party says that SSIS tools are supported by all versions of SQL servers 2005 and beyond apart from the Express
So can someone please confirm if SSIS tools are available for SQL server 2008 workgroup edition? I am only talking about deployment not development.

Someone has answered part of my question here but they were asking from the development point:
[[Can I run SSIS packages with SQL Server Express or Web or Workgroup editions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292564/can-i-run-ssis-packages-with-sql-server-express-or-web-or-workgroup-editions][1])

Thanks in advance,
Failsafe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, and the basic Integration Services features required by the wizard - these are the only Integration Services supported on the Workgroup Edition for SQL Server 2008.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.100).aspx

This link answers all questions regarding all versions.

Comment: Excellent link- It looks like SSIS tools will not work with the workgroup edition. Thank you.

Comment: Not a problem, if I solved your solution @failsafe could you bump this to provide indication of resolution?