# SQL Server Web Edition SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools, sql-agent

SSIS designer and runtime is not part of SQL Server 2014 Web edition.

Does this mean SSIS packages cannot be run as scheduled jobs on web edition via SQL Agent even if written on SSIS from the Developer version?

Comment: It will throw a license error!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-features-supported-by-the-editions-of-sql-server), ssis cannot be used in Web edition.

Also based on the answers of these questions, you will receive a license error while trying to do this:

- [Can I run SSIS packages with SQL Server Express or Web or Workgroup editions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292564/can-i-run-ssis-packages-with-sql-server-express-or-web-or-workgroup-editions)
- [Running scheduled SSIS pkg with SQL Server 2012 Web Edition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118347/running-scheduled-ssis-pkg-with-sql-server-2012-web-edition)

Comment: OK Thanks for your help

Comment: If this answer solved your question. You have to accept it. Just click on the mark under voting arrows

Comment: wilko.  Thanks again.